# Merge 2 different git repositories with nearly exact content

Tags: git, merge, repository

Right now I've two different repositories.
Repo 1: only the "core" and some "sys" modules. 
Repo 2: Got also "core", "sys" and also a lot of other stuff.
The problem is that the second repo isn't tracking or uploading any changes of core or sys modules and I've made a lot of changes in there. Core and sys didn't have had the same stage as core and sys had before I made these changes.

Now I wan't to sync "core" and "sys" from repo 2 with repo 1 and I does not have any idea of a slight solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: git remote add, fetch, merge.

Long one following.
Even if the repository are completely different (without a common ancestor) you can have the content of 2 repository in one.
On one repository (say repository A) use `git remote add` to add the second repository (say repository B).
Still in first repository (A) fetch the content of the second with `git fetch repository_B`.
What you get is a repository with the content of both.
You now can merge them. Say that you are in `master`, you can merge other repository master with a `git merge repository_B/master`.
Now you got a new commit with all content that you can push.

If you have lot of conflicts is better to attempt to make the 2 content more similar using `git diff` and incrementally update one or the other to reduce the differences. This could involve for instance `git mv` if the directory paths are different.